# Validate before going to next page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Peeps,

I see this question has been asked but they either don't have validation function right or there are some syntax errors.

Here is my code; it is supposed to check fields are not blank then if they are not blank it passes them to the next page.

What happens with my codes is that it does check the validation but right after the Alert pop-up it goes to the next page. My intention is to not go to the next page unless all fields are filled.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>      
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function RegValidation() {              
                var txtURL, 
                 if (!txtURL) {
                    alert("URL is mandatory!");
                    return false;
                  }
                 return true;
            }               
        </script>
</head> 
<body>  
        <form name="RegisterForm" action="RegConfirm.php" method="post">            

                <p><input type="text" name="txtURL"></p>

                <p><input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="Register()"></p>                                      
        </form>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    function Register() {

    if (!RegValidation()) return;        
     }

</script>
```

Comment: Dear lovely @mplungjan obviously I tried to cut this code out of 300 lines of code, so if the focus doesn't make sense I would expect YOU a coder to know it is used somewhere. You seem to be another I KNOW A LOT kinda person who instead of answering my question wrote some jibber jabber about what was not right about something else. I don't have problems with my code, I only want to know how to leash the button before going to the next page which you didn't give answer

Comment: sorry friend you are wrong. I have coded it myself. whether you believe or not is not my concern :). Happy coding

Comment: Wrong! I assumed people on this page are aware of coding and instead of picking on stupid unrelated things they try to be helpful..... I guess I'm in the wrong place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of onclick function on submit button try onsubmit in form tag..

the working code of the jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nLf5wy10/)

```
 <form name="RegisterForm" action="RegConfirm.php" method="post" onSubmit="return Register()">            

    <p><input type="text" name="txtURL" id="txtURL"></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Register"></p>                                      

 </form>



function Register() {
  return RegValidation();      
}

function RegValidation() {              
  var txtURL = document.getElementById('txtURL').value;
  if (!txtURL) {
     alert("URL is mandatory!");
     //   txtURLFocus();
     return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped :D

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to assign the value of the field to the var you are testing
2. You need a focus function that is not defined in the code you gave.
3. You now only execute a function on click instead of returning it. It is not recommended to assign handlers to a submit button so I have assigned it to the submit event where it belongs

Here is an unobtrusive working version

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("RegisterForm").onsubmit = function() {
    var txtURL = this.txtURL.valuel
    if (!txtURL) {
        alert("URL is mandatory!");
        this.txtURL.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="RegisterForm" id="RegisterForm" action="RegConfirm.php" method="post">

  <p><input type="text" name="txtURL"></p>

  <p><input type="submit" value="Register"></p>
</form>
```